# Closing a newly opened window on URL change jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to close the child window when there's a change in URL of the child window and open that URL in the parent window using jQuery. Any ideas on how to do that? I tried the following code to close the child window but it didn't work :

```
new_window = window.open(url, "_blank", "width=700,height=450,left=100,top=200")
$(new_window).on('hashchange', function(e) {
    new_window.close()
})
```

Comment: You need to run that code *within* the new window, and use  `window.close()`

Comment: Just a note, you don't have any `;` in your code sample. There should be one at the end of lines 1, 3, and 4. While I'm not sure if this would be the reason for your code failing, I figured it should be addressed.

Comment: @TylerRoper In Javascript semicolons after a statement can be omitted if it is followed by a line break or is the last one in a code block. So it is no issue in this case.